# PHP variable with multiple strings to an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, sum

This is extra code in a Drupal view table template so $row = the content I get..

```
var_dump($row);

// output:
array(5) { 
    ["field_datum"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["field_werf"]=> string(9) "Comis Cui" 
    ["field_machine"]=> string(17) "Graafmachien D293" 
    ["field_aantal_uren"]=> string(1) "5" 
    ["view_node"]=> string(50) "Bekijk" 
}

$uren = $row['field_aantal_uren'];
var_dump($uren);

// output: string(1) "5" string(1) "7" string(1) "1"
```

I've tried everything from explode, str_replace, preg_replace to get the 3 strings in an
array so I can loop over them them and make a sum. But I can't make it work..

Any suggestions to transform this variable to an array?

Comment: `$var1 + $var2 + $var3` ???

Comment: show us your code .. not just output

Comment: I think your question is incomplete

Comment: please post more code, your question makes no sense else...

Comment: in this case it outputs 'string '5' (length=1)' because this is the value of array key 'field_aantal_uren' what you need to get ?

Comment: yes this array returns 1 value, but with multiple results it returns something like // output: string(1) "5" string(1) "7" string(1) "1"

I would like to loop over them and sum them up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are `var_dump`ing from within a loop. try this:

```
$uren[] = $row['field_aantal_uren'];
```

and then OUTSIDE of the loop, you have your array.

```
echo array_sum($uren);
```